# how to pass data in form of array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, dropdown, ngx-select-dropdown

I am using the package [ngx select dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-dropdown) in my angular 5 project and wanted to know how I pass an array of objects instead of an array of strings.
Currently, If I am doing so it's showing [Object Object] as options in the dropdown.

```
data=[ {
        "id": "ab",
        "description": "аҧсуа"
    },
    {
        "id": "aa",
        "description": "Afaraf"
    },
    {
        "id": "af",
        "description": "Afrikaans"
    },
    {
        "id": "ak",
        "description": "Akan"
    }]
```

```
 <ngx-select-dropdown [config]="config" [options]="data" [(ngModel)]="datasel" [multiple]="false">
 </ngx-select-dropdown>
```

```
/** ngx-select-dropdown config */
    public config: any = {
        search: true,
        height: '260px',
        placeholder: 'Select',
        customComparator: () => { },
        limitTo: 10,
        moreText: 'more',
        noResultsFound: 'No results found!',
        searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
        searchOnKey: ''
    }
```

and I want to display description to users in dropdown and on select get id of the selected option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer to the question myself.
`config.displaykey` was missing, adding that key according to the requirement made it work.

```
/** ngx-select-dropdown config */
public config: any = {
    displayKey: "description",
    search: true,
    height: '260px',
    placeholder: 'Select',
    customComparator: () => { },
    limitTo: 10,
    moreText: 'more',
    noResultsFound: 'No results found!',
    searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
    searchOnKey: ''
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass `displayKey` in config if array of objects is passed

```
displayKey:"description"
```

check [here](https://github.com/manishjanky/ngx-select-dropdown#readme)